# mongo query with and operator

Tags: mongodb, meteor

in my meteor app I am trying to count the number of collection-items based on two fields, without success:

```
importantTilDatesCount: Entrys.findFromPublication('importantEntrys', { $and: [
    {"importantType" : { true }},
    {"importantDate" : { 
      $lt: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+7))
    }} 
  ]
}).count(),
```

"Entrys" is no typo ;)

Comment: Looks like you just want `true` not `{ true }`

Comment: You also almost never need `$and`. Your query therefore is `{ "importantType": true, "importantDate": { "$lt": new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+7)) } }`. You only ever need to specify `$and` where you must absolutely put multiple conditions on the same "key". Even then most often you do not need it. ie `{ "date" : { "$gt": yesterday, "$lte": today } }` Is actually just another form of an AND expression.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it was both. `true` instead of `{ true }`, as well as not specifying `$and`.